# Iterar en la promesa de una api llamando a otra api react js typescript

Tags: reactjs, api, typescript

Se que la pregunta es complicada pero basicamente es lo siguiente:

1. hago el llamado a una api que me devuelve un array de objetos
2. en la promesa de la api debo iterar este array para llamar a otro
   api
3. esto se hace para hacer match y crear un array con los datos del
   primer array y complementar con el segundo

el codigo queda asi

```
llamadoAPI1().then(response =>{
  let arreglo1:array = response.data;
  let arregloModificado:array=[];
  arreglo1.map(row =>{
        llamadoAPI2(row.id).then(response =>{  
        arregloModificado.push({response.data})  
      })
  })

})
```

todo bien hasta ahi, mi problema es cuando lo quiero renderizar, como el componente se renderiza antes de que la iteración termina, para cuando ya se recorre el arreglo entero, el componente ya se rendereo

quise obviar el hecho de que se usan state (useState) para asignar valor a las respuesta, estoy usando react js con typescript y hook

de que manera lo harian ustedes?

Comment: Hola amigo, deberías inicializar el objeto que despliega en el render con un [].
luego, actualizar el estado al terminar el segundo proceso, aplicando setState() a la variable de tu objeto que usas para render.
Normalmente para actualizar datos que puedan obtenerse asíncronamente puedes usar el hook componentDidMount.
para poder apoyarte con el código por favor publícalo.

Comment: Puedes intentar usar `async` y `await` para evitar confusiones

Comment: Te aparece un error? podrias hacer un lazy loading, para que mientras haces la iteracion se muestre un "cargando..."